# USB Debugging option not available

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

I am currently facing a problem with an Android Tablet, the tablet is working on 2.3.4 and it's a specific tablet (not a usual brand such as Samsung...).

Information on the tablet :

- Filesystem : Release 4.6.4-r171
- Kernel : 2.6.35.3-g56a157f
- It's seems to be a MX 93 (freescale)

I want to connect it for debugging. The problem is there is no "Debugging USB" option to check in the Parameters => Application => Developpment.

Have you any ideas on how to do it ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable ADB manually you need to configure USB interface and `start adbd` service on the device. First of all install a terminal emulator application. In the terminal run this command:

```
setprop sys.usb.config adb
```

If you are lucky and adbd service is properly pre-configured on your device it should start enumerating now.

If not - try looking for `start adbd` in the `init*usb.rc` files in the `/` folder. The lines before that command should give you an idea what else could be missing.